# Avalilability Zones and their absence in Azure

Tags: azure, high-availability, resiliency, azure-availability-zones

Availability Zones are not available in all regions in Azure yet.

So, in the absence of this feature what are some HA alternatives adopted by customers ?

Answer (score 0):

usually its combination of built-in geo redundancy with the one you implement on your own (say, Azure SQL replication + VMs in 2 regions) and traffic manager\azure front door on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, not all regions have Availability Zones. For VM's, you can use Availability Sets to get pretty close to the SLA for AZ's. 
You should not really use multiple regions as an high-availability option if your workload is latency-sensitive. Regions should be considered for DR.